# Convert regex syntax to glob (switching from Mercurial to Git)

Tags: git, mercurial, glob

Because Bitbucket are winding down their support for Mercurial, I'm switching over from Mercurial to Git on a number of projects. It seems straightforward enough to do, but I need, I think, to make some manual changes to my .hgignore files for them to be usable as .gitignore, as they use regex syntax which I don't think Git supports.

I have to say I'm not clear about how one does things like make patterns only applicable to root level. I'm hoping that someone can give me the glob equivalent of the following example lines from my .hgignore:

```
\.project
\.settings/
\.idea/
^out/
web-app/WEB-INF/classes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that Mercurial's `.hgignore` is (much) more flexible than Git's `.gitignore`, becuase Mercurial supports regular expressions *and* glob syntax.  However, glob syntax tends to be much easier to get right, and I recommend it even in Mercurial (it used to be slow but now globs are translated into regex internally so there should be no real speed penalty).

The equivalent of `\.project` is just `.project`.<sup>1</sup>  The equivalent of `\.settings/` is just `.settings/`.  This also works for `.idea/`.  The only slightly difficult ones here are `^out/` and `web-app/WEB-INF/classes`.  You *certainly* want:

```
/out/
```

which in Git anchors the `out/` part to the level at which the `.gitignore` file appears, and you *probably* want a simple:

```
web-app/WEB-INF/classes
```

unless you mean to match the two-name-component-series `web-app/WEB-INF` at any level underneath this point and unless you mean to match `classes.*` (in regex terms) after that.  In those cases you may want:

```
**/web-app/WEB-INF/classes*
```

or similar.  The reason for the leading `**/` is that in Git `.gitignore` files, any glob pattern with an *embedded* slash is equivalent to the same one starting with a leading slash.  That is:

```
$ cat .gitignore
foo
```

This tells Git not to complain about a file or directory named `foo` at *any level underneath this point*, i.e., in this folder or any sub-folder.  On the other hand:

```
$ cat .gitignore
/foo
```

means *only `foo` at the top level*, which also makes sense to everyone.  But the weird thing is that:

```
bar/foo
```

means exactly the same thing as:

```
/bar/foo
```

because the embedded (not trailing) slash means "match only in this folder", just as a leading slash would.

(*Trailing* slashes mean "only a subdirectory / sub-folder should match this rule".  They get removed just for the "is there a slash" test; if there is a slash after removing any trailing one, the whole thing is anchored to this particular folder / directory.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If I needed more ammunition in favor of glob instead of regex, `\.project` was probably *wrong* as it also excludes a file named `this.project.file`.  But if you really *did* mean the equivalent of `^.*\.project.*$`, that one is hard to express with glob patterns.